# Reverse the order of key, value in an array conversion to a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Suppose I have an array of values, then keys (the reverse of what an assignment to a hash would expect):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my @arr = qw(1 one 2 two 3 three 4 four 1 uno 2 dos 3 tres 4 cuatro);

my %hash = @arr;

dd \%hash;
```

Prints

```
{ 1 => "uno", 2 => "dos", 3 => "tres", 4 => "cuatro" }
```

Obviously, the duplicate keys are eliminated when the hash is constructed.

How can I reverse the order of the pairs of values used to construct the hash?

I know that I can write a C style loop:

```
for(my $i=1; $i<=$#arr; $i=$i+2){
    $hash{$arr[$i]}=$arr[$i-1];
    }

dd \%hash;   
# { cuatro => 4, dos => 2, four => 4, one => 1, three => 3, tres => 3, two => 2, uno => 1 }
```

But that seems a little clumsy. I am looking for something a little more idiomatic Perl.

In Python, I would just do `dict(zip(arr[1::2], arr[0::2]))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html):

```
my %hash = reverse @arr;
```

A list of the built-in functions in Perl is in [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).

Comment: Doh! Of course! That even makes the Python look more complicated!

Comment: Use [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) as a reference to find functions. I found it very useful when I learned Perl.

Comment: I knew about `reverse`; I just did not connect that it would work to reverse the entire array since in Python the construction of an associative array needs to be in tuples of key, value pairs. I was stuck in thinking that I needed to reverse each pair rather than (now, obviously) just reversing the entire array

Answer (score 4):

[TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729271/970195) has the right answer, but the other way to avoid eliminating dup keys is to use hash of arrays. I am assuming that's the reason for you reversing the array in the first place.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my @arr = qw(1 one 2 two 3 three 4 four 1 uno 2 dos 3 tres 4 cuatro);

my %hash;

push @{ $hash{$arr[$_]} }, $arr[$_ + 1] for grep { not $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#arr;

dd \%hash;
```

#### Output:

```
{
  1 => ["one", "uno"],
  2 => ["two", "dos"],
  3 => ["three", "tres"],
  4 => ["four", "cuatro"],
}
```

As suggested by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729198/reverse-the-order-of-key-value-in-an-array-conversion-to-a-hash/25729449?noredirect=1#comment40226068_25729449) in the comments, you can take a look at the [List::Pairwise](http://search.cpan.org/~tdrugeon/List-Pairwise-1.03/lib/List/Pairwise.pod) module available on CPAN for a more readable solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;
use List::Pairwise qw( mapp ); 

my @arr = qw(1 one 2 two 3 three 4 four 1 uno 2 dos 3 tres 4 cuatro);

my %hash;

mapp { push @{ $hash{$a} }, $b } @arr;

dd \%hash;
```

Comment: Your answer has foresight. I was just looking at doing this as well. Thanks!

Comment: really nice - extremely compact. :)

Comment: +1, I can only speculate why @ikegami didn't mention corelib List::Util http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%24count-%3d-pairmap-%7b-BLOCK-%7d-%40kvlist

Answer (score 0):

TLP has the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729271/298607) if your array of value, keys are ready to go into the hash.

That said, if you want to process the key or value in anyway before they go into the hash, I find this to be something I use:

```
while (my ($v, $k)=(shift @arr, shift @arr)) {
    last unless defined $k;
    # xform $k or $v in someway, like $k=~s/\s*$//; to strip trailing whitespace...
    $hash{$k}=$v;
}
```

(Note -- destructive to the array `@arr`. If you want to use `@arr` for something else, make a copy of it first.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: The loop is destructive to the array. If you want to keep your original array value, you need to copy it, no?

Comment: The advantage here is that like `zip` in Python, this loop truncates the odd out key or value. In Perl the assignment of `%hash = @arr;` will die of not the right number of key, values.

Comment: @thewolf Actually it will not cause the Perl program to die, but it will issue a warning `Odd number of elements in hash assignment`. Though if you use `use warnings FATAL => 'all';` you can make it die, if you like stricter code.